# How to whois ARIN to get IP ranges?

Tags: arin

I'd like to know how, using command-line whois, I can get all IP ranges (i.e., NET objects) assigned to a particular organisation.

For example, consider this company: http://whois.arin.net/rest/org/HT-136 ... if you click on the link "Related networks" it will bring you to http://whois.arin.net/rest/org/HT-136/nets which shows you the networks assigned to it.

I am finding it difficult to figure out how to get the same info using command-line whois.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ whois -a "o ! >  HT-136"
```

As found by doing `man whois` and `whois -a ?`

- -a

  > Use the American Registry for Internet Numbers (ARIN) database.
  >   It contains network numbers used in those parts of the world cov-
  >   ered neither by APNIC, AfriNIC, LACNIC, nor by RIPE.
- o

  > Query-by-record-type:
  >        o       Organizations
- !

  > Query-by-attribute:
  >        !          Searches for matches by handle or id
- >

  > Record hierarchy:
  >                 Displays the record related down the hierarchy.
  >                 For an organization or customer, display
  >                 the resources registered to that organization or customer, in
  >                 list format.

The Result is:

```
#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# http://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml
#


#
# The following results may also be obtained via:
# http://whois.arin.net/rest/orgs;handle=HT-136?showDetails=true&ext=netref2
#

OrgName:        HAProxy Technologies, Inc.
OrgId:          HT-136
Address:        1013 Centre Road, Suite 403S
City:           Wilmington
StateProv:      DE
PostalCode:     19805
Country:        US
RegDate:        2014-04-02
Updated:        2014-07-18
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/org/HT-136

TechHandle: SCARP14-ARIN
TechName:   Scarpa, John
TechPhone:  +1-857-366-5050
TechEmail:  john.scarpa@haproxy.com
TechRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/SCARP14-ARIN

TechHandle: BRKIC2-ARIN
TechName:   Brkic, andrej
TechPhone:  +19547320642
TechEmail:  abrkic@haproxy.com
TechRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/BRKIC2-ARIN

NOCHandle: NETWO6774-ARIN
NOCName:   Network Operations
NOCPhone:  +1-857-366-5050
NOCEmail:  noc@haproxy.com
NOCRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/NETWO6774-ARIN

AdminHandle: SCARP14-ARIN
AdminName:   Scarpa, John
AdminPhone:  +1-857-366-5050
AdminEmail:  john.scarpa@haproxy.com
AdminRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/SCARP14-ARIN

AbuseHandle: NETWO6775-ARIN
AbuseName:   Network Abuse
AbusePhone:  +1-857-366-5050
AbuseEmail:  abuse@haproxy.com
AbuseRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/NETWO6775-ARIN
HAProxy Technologies, Inc. SCNET-205-234-170-0-1 (NET-205-234-170-0-1) 205.234.170.0 - 205.234.170.255
HAProxy Technologies, Inc. SCNET-205-234-181-0-1 (NET-205-234-181-0-1) 205.234.181.0 - 205.234.181.255
HAProxy Technologies, Inc. SCNET-205-234-165-0-1 (NET-205-234-165-0-1) 205.234.165.0 - 205.234.165.255
HAProxy Technologies, Inc. SCNET-205-234-166-0-1 (NET-205-234-166-0-2) 205.234.166.0 - 205.234.166.255
HAProxy Technologies, Inc. HAPNET-1 (NET-104-152-112-0-1) 104.152.112.0 - 104.152.119.255
HAProxy Technologies, Inc. (AS11019) HAPROXY-TECHNOLOGIES 11019



#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# http://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml
#
```

---

As an alternate answer, using CURL or any REST client via RWHOIS is in my opinion MUCH easier to parse.

`curl http://whois.arin.net/rest/org/HT-136/nets`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='http://whois.arin.net/xsl/website.xsl' ?>
<nets xmlns="http://www.arin.net/whoisrws/core/v1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.arin.net/whoisrws/rdns/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://www.arin.net/whoisrws/netref/v2" termsOfUse="https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html" inaccuracyReportUrl="http://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml">
   <limitExceeded limit="256">false</limitExceeded>
   <netRef startAddress="205.234.170.0" endAddress="205.234.170.255" name="SCNET-205-234-170-0-1" handle="NET-205-234-170-0-1">http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-205-234-170-0-1</netRef>
   <netRef startAddress="205.234.181.0" endAddress="205.234.181.255" name="SCNET-205-234-181-0-1" handle="NET-205-234-181-0-1">http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-205-234-181-0-1</netRef>
   <netRef startAddress="205.234.165.0" endAddress="205.234.165.255" name="SCNET-205-234-165-0-1" handle="NET-205-234-165-0-1">http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-205-234-165-0-1</netRef>
   <netRef startAddress="205.234.166.0" endAddress="205.234.166.255" name="SCNET-205-234-166-0-1" handle="NET-205-234-166-0-2">http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-205-234-166-0-2</netRef>
   <netRef startAddress="104.152.112.0" endAddress="104.152.119.255" name="HAPNET-1" handle="NET-104-152-112-0-1">http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-104-152-112-0-1</netRef>
</nets>
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the REST service, however, some RIRs don't provide this and ideally I'd like to be able to query all of them, so a whois commandline might be more portable between each RIR.

Comment: Unfortunately, ARIN puts a hard limit of 256 results to Whois-RWS child network queries and also didn't implement [ACSP Suggestion 2012.20: Remove result limit for Whois-RWS child network queries](https://www.arin.net/participate/community/acsp/suggestions/2012/2012-20/), as of writing, for 10 years now, thus this answer unfortunately works practically only for non-large organisation.